# Remote desktop aternative to Teamviewer that can block inputs on remote PC+turn remote screen black

Tags: remote-desktop

Teamviewer recently decided to cut off the Block Remote User Input and Show Black Screen from Free users, and limit it to Business+ plans (starts at $50/month...yikes!).

So was looking to an alternative that can allow me to black out the remote screen, preferably for free, or  low-cost subscription (preferably not >$5/month please).